# Is there a way to change the document root of a PHP project added to and existing project directory?

Tags: php

So I'm working on a PHP project for work, and my boss wants to have it deployed to an existing web app directory. The problem is that in my app when I redirect to index.php, Apache will redirect to the index of the existing project, not my project that's in a child folder. I need to have it so all my links will be relative to my project folder. I also can't change the redirects to '/myproject/index.php' because this needs to work as a standalone app as well (without being added on to an existing directory). I know this isn't an ideal scenario; I suggested virtual hosts but it was turned down.

Clarification:

The root of the existing web app is: /

When deployed to that web app's directory the root of my project is: '/myproject/'

The solution I came up with is to have an environment file where, during setup, someone can specify which directory will be the root directory. But that can be cumbersome to use. Just wondering if there's a more elegant solution out there.

How I'm using the environment file:

```
<?php
// In a folder above my project folder.
$abs_root_path = __DIR__ . '/..';

// Using phpdotenv for environment variables.
require($abs_root_path . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/..');
$dotenv->load();

// $_ENV['ROOT'] = /myproject/
$relative_root = $_ENV['ROOT'];

header("location: $relative_root");
```

Appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically just used the environment variable solution I posted in my question, since there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing this.

Comment: Doesn't `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` have what you want?